# pixi container hitarea with mask

Tags: html, canvas, web, mask, pixi.js

I create a container then add some points to it , and create a mask on the container, make the container moveable , outside the container , there are some displayObject which are clickable ;

but when I move the container, the displayObject is masked by the container , it is not clickable;

what is worse, the point is invisible but clickable outside the mask ,
seems mask only make it opacity:0 , It's not correct !

here see more visible

https://i.loli.net/2017/12/26/5a42693ec8e5a.gif

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a z-index issue, try to add the clickable displayObjects using stage.addChild() **after** adding the the moveable container.

If for some reason, you cannot add the clickable displayObjects after adding the moveable container, consider using stage.addChildAt(child, childIndex)